# MVC Razor View loses Variable scope inside for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor view that loses the variable scope once inside the forloop.  It works fine until I added the table tags. So all my calls to the different parts of the ViewModel no longer work. Please let me know if there is anything else that would help to know.

```
@model Auditor_Evaluations_MVC.ViewModels.EvaluationViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <table class="table table-condensed" style="width:825px;"> 
            for(int i = 0; i < Model.QuestionGroup.Count; i++)
            {       
                var questionGroup = Model.QuestionGroup[i];
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.QuestionGroup[i].GroupName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.QuestionGroup[i].GroupId)
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">@Html.Label(questionGroup.GroupName) </th>
                        <th class="text-center">Excellent</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Good</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Fair</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Poor</th>
                        <th class="text-center">N/A</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                var questions = questionGroup.Questions;
                for(int j = 0; j < questions.Count; j++)
                {  
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.QuestionGroup[i].Questions[j].QuestionName)     
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">@Html.Label(questions[j].QuestionName) </td>
                            var questionResponse = questions[j].QuestionResponses;
                            @for(int k = 0; k < questionResponse.Count; k++)
                            {
                                <td class="text-center" style="width:75px">
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.QuestionGroup[i].Questions[j].SelectedAnswer,questionResponse[k].QuestionValue)

                                </td>
                            }

                    </tr>

                }   
                }             


            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><strong>@Model.GeneralQuestion1Text</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.GeneralQuestion1Value)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><strong>2. Additional Comments:</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.GeneralQuestion2Value)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><strong>3. Would you like the appropriate audit manager to contact you regarding any or all of the information relayed through this questionnaire? If yes, please include your name and telephone number.</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.GeneralQuestion3Value)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: what variable scope are you talking about ? What is not working ?

Comment: The scope of i, the scope of j, and the scope of k.  Even inside the for loops.

Comment: How do you know it is not available  ? Did you try to print them in your razor and verify ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on exactly what your problem is, the question is a little confusiing, but all the places where you do something like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.QuestionGroup[i].GroupName)
```

Should probably be replaced with

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionGroup[i].GroupName)
```

i.e. use the `m` variable to represent your model in the lambda expression, rather than referencing the `Model` property.

Also, on this line:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="width:825px;"> 
     for(int i = 0; i < Model.QuestionGroup.Count; i++)
```

You need to add an `@` in front of the `for` keyword.

Comment: For Example I get this error  Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Here are the lines 

Line 8:              {       
Line 9:                  var questionGroup = Model.QuestionGroup[i];
Line 10:                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionGroup[i].GroupName)
Line 11:                 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionGroup[i].GroupId)
Line 12:                 <thead>

Comment: You've got a few syntax errors, but they should be easy enough to spot if you're using Visual Studio - if the keywords (e.g. `for`) are not coloured like you would expect (the default is blue) then Razor doesn't know that it's supposed to be code.  It's treating the for loop as plain text.

Comment: Thank you, it was a missing @.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `foreach` in that Razor block

```
foreach(var question in Model.QuestionGroup) {
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.question.GroupName)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.question.GroupId)
...
etc.
```

update: you may need to look into the [EditorFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949(v=vs.100).aspx) and [EditorForModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorformodel(v=vs.100).aspx) HTML helpers if your model is not mapping to the correct ViewModel when send it

Comment: If you use a `foreach` like this then the input names/ids that are generated will result in the model binding not working when the form is posted back to the server.  It does make the code easier to write though :)

Comment: true that! however - with proper nesting of ViewModels it should be possible

Comment: I did at first use the foreach and it was just giving me a headache with posting the model to the controller. Now its working! :)